# How to create a simple chrome:extension that allows a developer on a site to access chrome.windows

Tags: google-chrome-extension

here is my manifest..

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "Blah blah",
"description": "Blah blah",
"version": "1.0",

"browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "calculator-16.png",
  "default_popup": "calculator-128.html"
},
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

when I console.log(chrome) in my app i get this..

```
Object {webstore: Object, runtime: Object, app: Object}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`chrome.windows` is only allowed to be accessed inside chrome extension context (background page, options page, popup page).

For your case, you could right click your browser action and select inspect popup, inside the console window it opens, just type `chrome`, it will show what you want.